# XML file to std:out (formated) with Apache Camel

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache, apache-camel

I want to print to console a formatted XML file with Apache Camel:

Expected output is:

XML ->

```
<client book="Camel in Action" author="4995" title="1"/>
```

std:out ->

```
Client
book: Camel in Action
author: 4995
title: 1
```

my currently code:

```
    public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

        JAXBContext jaxbContext =    
        JAXBContext.newInstance(Client.class);
        JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat = new  
        JaxbDataFormat(jaxbContext);


        from("file:/home/tkaczmarek/usr/data/inbox/")
            .unmarshal(jaxbDataFormat)
            .to("file:/home/tkaczmarek/usr/data/outbox")
            .log("${body}");
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Client {

@XmlAttribute
private String book;

@XmlAttribute
private String author;

@XmlAttribute
private String title;
}
```

How I can get expected output? Now it's just printing to std:out just xml file with tags :(

Comment: If you remove unmarshal(jaxbDataFormat)?

Comment: Not working, same output as before delete

Comment: Put a .to("log...") between unmarshal and to("file...")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I don't exactly understand what you're up to but, instead of `log()`, you could use `bean()` as shown below to print the *unmarshalled* xml and format it in whatever way you want.

```
from("file:/home/tkaczmarek/usr/data/inbox/")
    .to("file:/home/tkaczmarek/usr/data/outbox")
    .bean(XmlToBean.class);
```

Here is the `XmlToBean` class-

```
public class XmlToBean {
    public void transformXmlObject(Client client){
        System.out.println(client.toString());
    }
}
```

Notice that I haven't even used the `unmarshal()` as it's needed only in the classpath, unless you've some specific requirements. If you think adding another class is overkill, a `process()` would also have sufficed as shown below-

```
from("file:/home/tkaczmarek/usr/data/inbox/")
    .to("file:/home/tkaczmarek/usr/data/outbox")
    .process(exchange -> {
        System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(Client.class));
    });
```